# how to create multiple derived objects on the heap with different parameters through a function

Tags: c++, inheritance, pointers

I have a derived class from base:

```
class base{ 
public:
base(){};
~base(){}
};

class derived : public base{
public:
derived(int & input): a(input){};
~derived(){};

int a;
};
```

i have a pointer that intiate the derived class on the heap as follows

```
main()
{
int b=10;
base * b1;
b1=new derived(b);
factory(b1,5);
    }
```

I want to pass this pointer b1 into a function factory to recreate multiple instance of b1 after changing the value of b like:

```
    void factory(base *p_base,int input_integer)
{
    for(int m=0; m<=input_integer,m++){
    b=m;
    base *b1_duplicate (new p_base);
};
```

but this doesnt compile! how can i use the pointer as took to recreate multiple instance of the derived class after changing the pointer parameters in each step.

Comment: It should be "base *b1(new derived (b));"

Comment: base* is a pointer to a base object.  *base is a compile error.

Comment: In your "derived" constructor, why do you write "int & input" instead of "int input"? Tne way you've written it, it is pointless, but I think what you were *trying* to do there is central to your question, so please clarify.

Comment: there are too many errors, please read a book about C++ syntax

Comment: And even if we were to correct all the errors so that it compiles, we're still divided on what "how can i use the pointer as took to recreate multiple instance of the derived class after changing the pointer parameters in each step." means. Is it a question?

Comment: Sorry all the code was written poorly. The whole idea is that i have lots of derived classes, each of which will have different parameters in the constructor say derived1(int), derived2(string). The idea was to define something like base * b1 (new derived1(b)) and * b2 (new derived2(string) and pass them to a function that creates different instances of them as parameters in the constructor  rather than building 2 blocks of loop to recreate them.

Answer (score 3):

This code is just dreadful.

Some suggestions:

#### 1) The following is illegal:

```
class base{ 
base(){};
~base(){}
};

class derived : public base{
};
```

In order to derive from base, the constructor and destructor need to be public or protected.

#### 2) The following is wrong:

```
*base b1(new (derived(b));
```

Pointers are declared as:

```
TYPE* name;
```

#### 3) This won't work

```
base b1(new (derived(b));
```

since you need a constructor that takes a pointer to a `derived` object as parameter.

### 4) Your factory method makes my eyes hurt.

Comment: sorry there was a typo in line *base b1(new derived(b)). This now reads properly !

Comment: -1 I don't disagree with what you said, I just don't like the way you're saying it.

Comment: In order to derive from `Base`, the destructor and any constructors used by the derived class must be accessible in the derived class.  They can be either public or protected.

Comment: I have made all constructors and destructors public. I understand that. The constructor of derived takes and integer. By saying *base b1(new derived(b)), I understand that i'm declaring a pointer to base and assigning it a new derived object with b value. which is fine. How can i get the factory function to works from my quesiton above!

Comment: @AElansary WRONG! *base b1(new derived(b)) does not declare a pointer to a base. Read my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

Your C++ syntax is completely off... Shows absolutely no sense of C++ or C programming for that matter. This looks as if you are TRYING to derive some concepts out of either javascript type inheritance or something equally ugly.

Is this homework? Factory function as you define it is meaningless. Even if you create multiple instances of b what are you doing with those instances in the factory?

Your declarations of variables is completely incorrect. You need to read up on a C++ primer before attempting programming.

Okay so now to get on the right path:

In order to declare a class which will have derived classes the creator and destructor have to be public or protected scope. Whereas by default (if you don't specify scope) it is private to the class.

Also, if your derived class has a destructor then base destructor has to be virtual.

So:

```
class Base { 
      public Base() { }
      public virtual ~Base() { }
};

class Derived : public Base {

      int a;

      public Derived(int _a) : a(_a) { Base(); }
      public virtual ~Derived() { }
};
```

You are confusing the syntax for dereferencing a pointer with declaring a pointer to a type.  So declaration of a pointer to a type TYPE is as following:

```
   TYPE * ptype;
```

where `ptype` is the variable that is of `TYPE *` type (pointer to TYPE)

e.g.

```
   int *pnum;
```

pnum holds the address of memory location that points to an integer type.

You can use pnum to point to an integer:

```
   int x = 5;
   pnum = &x;  // read this line as 'pnum refers to x' or 'pnum points to x' or
               // pnum is the memory address of x.
```

If you want to access the integer value pointed to by pnum you can "dereference" the memory pointer you use the `*pnum`

```
   cout << "Address of x in memory (stored in pnum) is: " << pnum << endl
        << "Value of x (pointed to by pnum is: " << *pnum << endl;
```

So to declare a pointer to the base class:

```
   Base *b;
```

To instantiate a derived class using the base class pointer:

```
   b = new Derived(10);
```

In order to instantiate a number of these and save instances in an array:

```
   int count = 10;
   Base **b = new Base[count];

   for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
          b[i] = new Derived(i);
   }
```

If any of this is confusing in any way ... and I mean you that you struggle for more than 30seconds to understand it. Then it indicates that you need to start learning C++ from scratch.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed for explaining. I'm a beginner in C++! if i take your last 2 blocks of code and say  b = new Derived(m) . how can you duplicate "b" in a loop within a function. i.e void (base* pointer){for  (int i=0; i<5; i++){m=i; b[i]= ??}; the whole idea is to use b as handle or short cut to reproduce derived? thanks again

Comment: okay so if you look at the very last piece of code segment in my example it does exactly that... there `Base **b` is actually an ARRAY of pointers to B. the count in that case is 10 elements in the array. You need to read up on C/C++ arrays first.  Then that code will make sense to you.

Comment: i understand that? how can you feed the array without actually writing new derived(i) on the right hand side but rather than the declaration that we gave the pointer earlier wich is b. is there a change to replace "b" into the right-hand side of  b[i] = new Derived(i)! or this relational feature doesnt happen in c++.

Comment: Okay you're definitely missing the point here... What is your programming background? May be i can explain the code in those terms. If you have no programming background then that block is not going to make sense to you until you understand arrays in C++.  If you cannot interpret the last piece of code (which stores 10 different instances in the b[0] ... b[9]  each initialized by Derived(0) ... Derived(9) respectively) in the array b[] then you are not ready for classes yet. you have to understand arrays, for loops, variables even.